# How to optimise nested loop in dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to optimise the iteration because there is long time needed ti finalise operation and this is my code
[image: the first table]
[the second table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EuJ9.png)

```
l=0
for i in df_MailBox_Total.index : 
    if pd.isnull(df_MailBox_Total.at[i,'ReceivedOrgId']):
        for j in df_SentMail_Service.index :
            if df_MailBox_Total.at[i,'MailId'] == df_SentMail_Service.at[j,'MailID']:
               df_MailBox_Total.at[i,'ReceivedOrgId'] =df_SentMail_Service.at[j,'OrgID']
               l=l+1
               break;
```

l

Comment: The logic is when i find MailId in the second dataframe i update  the value of the first dataframe but: the in two dataframe i have 500k records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use this :

```
df_MailBox_Total = (df_MailBox_Total
                         .set_index('MailId')
                         .assign(ReceivedOrgId = lambda x: x["ReceivedOrgId"]
                                .fillna(df_SentMail_Service.set_index('MailID')['OrgID']))
                         .reset_index())
```

Comment: it is the error found : cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels